# Show data in columns by week name in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert columns by week name in SQL Server.

This is my example:

```
Id  Value   ondate
1   10      06/05/2013      
2   9       07/05/2013      
3   5       08/05/2013      
4   89      09/05/2013      
5   8       10/05/2013
```

Scenario #1:

- start date : 06/05/2013 (monday)
- End date : 14/05/2013 (thursday)

This is my result:

```
       mo   tu  we  th  fr  sa  su
row1   10   9   5   89  8   23  3
row2    5   8
```

Scenario #2:

- start date : 06/05/2013 (monday)
- End date : 07/05/2013 (thursday)

This is my desired result:

```
        mo   tu
row1    10    9
```

How can I build the result?

Comment: @AnilDiggiwal : What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum(case...` as below to pivot the data across days as columns (or look into the `PIVOT` operator).  Also, consider how multiple years might affect your results, and adjust the grouping accordingly.

```
set dateformat dmy;
set datefirst 1; --monday

declare @YourTable table (Id int, Value int, ondate datetime)
insert into @YourTable
    select 1,   10, '06/05/2013' union all     
    select 2,   9,  '07/05/2013' union all      
    select 3,   5,  '08/05/2013' union all      
    select 4,   89, '09/05/2013' union all      
    select 5,   8,  '10/05/2013' union all
    select 6,   23, '11/05/2013' union all
    select 7,   3,  '12/05/2013' union all
    select 8,   5,  '13/05/2013' union all
    select 9,   8,  '14/05/2013'

select  [mo]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Monday' then Value else 0 end),
        [tu]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Tuesday' then Value else 0 end),
        [we]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Wednesday' then Value else 0 end),
        [th]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Thursday' then Value else 0 end),
        [fr]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Friday' then Value else 0 end),
        [sa]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Saturday' then Value else 0 end),
        [su]=sum(case when datename(weekday, ondate) = 'Sunday' then Value else 0 end)
from    @YourTable
where   ondate between '06/05/2013' and '14/05/2013'
group
by      datepart(week, ondate);

-- Result:
/*
mo  tu  we  th  fr  sa  su
10  9   5   89  8   23  3
5   8   0   0   0   0   0
*/
```

Comment: If you want to omit columns then you'll have to use dynamic sql. IMO, this sort of thing is best done in presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `PIVOT`:-

```
Declare @startDate datetime,@endDate datetime
Set @startDate = '05/06/2013' 
Set @endDate = '05/14/2013'


Select  sum([Monday]) as Mo,sum([Tuesday]) as Tu,
        sum([wednesday]) as Wed,sum([Thursday]) as Th,sum([Friday]) as Fr,
        sum([Saturday]) as St,sum([Sunday]) as Su
from 
(
  Select value,datename(weekday,ondate) as dayName,ondate
  from @Sample 
  where ondate >= @startDate and ondate <= @endDate
)p
pivot
(
 min(value)
 for dayName in ([Monday],[Tuesday],[wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],
                 [Saturday],[Sunday])
)pvt
group by datename(week,ondate)
```

Output for start date : 05/06/2013 (monday)
           End date   : 05/14/2013 (thursday)

```
 ╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
 ║ Mo ║  Tu  ║ Wed  ║  Th  ║  Fr  ║  St  ║  Su  ║
 ╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
 ║ 10 ║ 9    ║ 5    ║ 89   ║ 8    ║ 23   ║ 3    ║
 ║ 12 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
 ╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Output for start date : 05/06/2013 (monday)
           End date   : 05/07/2013 (thursday)

```
 ╔════╦════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
 ║ Mo ║ Tu ║ Wed  ║  Th  ║  Fr  ║  St  ║  Su  ║
 ╠════╬════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
 ║ 10 ║  9 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
 ╚════╩════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f605/5)

Comment: thx for Help but Scenario #2 not match in query...
start date : 06/05/2013 (monday)
End date : 07/05/2013 (thursday) so no show extra columns

Comment: All kinds of presentation stuff should be done at the front end . SQL Server is not meant for that . What are trying to achieve .Kindly be more specific in your requirement . Do you need to show the data in reports ?